# Android: How to delete an item permanently in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented my application based on this reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luxE7oEKiic However, the items that i have deleted will automatically be added back into the list upon restarting of the application. Any idea what can i do to delete the item permanently?

```
private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private AppAdapter listadapter = null;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
   list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    listadapter = new AppAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_list_app, applist);
    list.setAdapter(listadapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    list.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
            listadapter.removeSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
            arg0.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, arg1);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = listadapter.getSelectedIds();

                    for(int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                        if(selected.valueAt(i)) {
                            ApplicationInfo selecteditem = listadapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                            listadapter.remove(selecteditem);
                        }
                    }
                    arg0.finish();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = list.getCheckedItemCount();
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            listadapter.toggleSelection(position);

        }

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

    try{
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

        if(intent != null){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list){
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> appList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for(ApplicationInfo info : list){
        try{
            if(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)!=null){
                appList.add(info);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return appList;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        listadapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_list_app, applist);
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        setListAdapter(listadapter);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading apps info...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you are going to get the same data once you restart. The data is static.

Comment: Can you show the code for `LoadApplications` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is coming from a source when you call `new LoadApplications().execute();`.

This Task grabs all the items from the source list. In order to remove the item completely (so that, even after the app is closed and re opened) You need to save a list of items deleted by the user in a Database or Shared Preferences.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
        switch (arg1.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                SparseBooleanArray selected = listadapter.getSelectedIds();

                for(int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                    if(selected.valueAt(i)) {
                        ApplicationInfo selecteditem = listadapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                        listadapter.remove(selecteditem);

                        // Save the selected item in a Content Provider/Shared Pref 
                    }
                }
                arg0.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

And in the `postExecute` method of `LoadApplications` class remove the items stored in Database or Shared Preferences from the list returned from the source, before calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

        // Remove the items me stored in the removedList

        listadapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_list_app, applist);
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        setListAdapter(listadapter);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading apps info...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

To give you a quick start. You can use this very easy to use Class [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) to save your list. But I would recommend you to go through Content Providers and SharedPrefs in detail.

Comment: I have uploaded the method LoadApplication. I have read about Share Preferences but there isn't a clear example for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the modified data in `onSaveInstanceState`. When you 'restart' the activity, check the `savedInstanceState` Bundle first. If it's not null, restore data from the `Bundle` instead of getting it from the original source.

If you mean a start without `savedInstanceState`, you must modify the source of data. If you cannot, you can record your operations or the modified data in your own storage.

Comment: You mean i should move my methods into onSaveInstance instead(i have uploaded my code)? Pardon me for asking as i am new to android studio.

Comment: No, just save the data in `onSaveInstanceState`. But if your app is completely killed, this won't work. If the source of data remain unchanged, the data every time you retrieve are the same. Unless you use a custom storage like sqlite or shared preference to store the modified data.